# How to set up and compile a binary for format string attacks?

Tags: c, gcc, format-string

I wanted to practise format strings attack, so i wrote a small program

`format.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char input[1024];

int main() {

    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    printf(input);

}
```

I compiled it with `gcc-7 format.c -o format -m32 -no-pie`.
Now i tried following to see if my supplied string is in memory: `python -c 'print "AAAA" + " %x"*50' | ./format`

Output:

```
AAAA 400 f7f995c0 804918a ffffd3e0 0 0 f7de07e1 f7f99000 f7f99000 0 f7de07e1 1 ffffd474 ffffd47c ffffd404 1 0 f7f99000 0 f7ffd000 0 f7f99000 f7f99000 0 f75cc795 b4f44185 0 0 0 1 8049060 0 f7fe9450 f7fe42d0 804c000 1 8049060 0 8049092 8049176 1 ffffd474 80491e0 8049240 f7fe42d0 ffffd46c 1c 1 ffffd5f9 0
```

I got lots of high addresses and other addresses, but i dont see my A's in memory. Can someone help me?

Comment: Show exact output.

Comment: @EsmaeelE Added the output.

Comment: Your `input` is not on the stack.

Comment: @the busybee thank you! If i want to get this to work, i have to use ```strcpy(buf, argv[1])``` or ```sprintf(buf, argv[1])``` etc.?